# Name columns with Dataframe name in a list of Dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

Objective: Change colname of dataframes in a list of dataframes to the name of each dataframe.

I have some issues when dealing with list and dataframes regarding its name. I have prepared this example to clarify. Hope it is not a mess.

### Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 3, B = 3, C = 2)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)
```

*Output:*

```
> str(dfList)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 1
  ..$ B: num 2
  ..$ C: num 3
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 3
  ..$ B: num 3
  ..$ C: num 2
> names(dfList)
NULL
> names(dfList$df1)
NULL
> names(dfList$df2)
NULL
```

*Manually Input names:*

```
names(dfList) <- c("df1", "df2") 
dfList <- lapply(dfList, setNames, c("A", "B", "C"))
```

*Which yields:*

```
> str(dfList)
List of 2
 $ df1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 1
  ..$ B: num 2
  ..$ C: num 3
 $ df2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 3
  ..$ B: num 3
  ..$ C: num 2
> names(dfList)
[1] "df1" "df2"
> names(dfList$df1)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
> names(dfList$df2)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

### Desired Solution:

```
WishedList <- dfList
WishedList[[1]] <- setNames(WishedList[[1]], c("A", "B", "df1"))
WishedList[[2]] <- setNames(WishedList[[2]], c("A", "B", "df2"))
```

*Output solution:*

```
> str(WishedList)
List of 2
 $ df1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A  : num 1
  ..$ B  : num 2
  ..$ df1: num 3
 $ df2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A  : num 3
  ..$ B  : num 3
  ..$ df2: num 2
> names(WishedList)
[1] "df1" "df2"
> names(WishedList$df1)
[1] "A"   "B"   "df1"
> names(WishedList$df2)
[1] "A"   "B"   "df2"
```

### MyTry:

```
TryList1 <- lapply(dfList, function(x) setNames(x, c("A", "B", quote(x))))
str(TryList1)
List of 2
 $ df1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 1
  ..$ B: num 2
  ..$ x: num 3
 $ df2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ A: num 3
  ..$ B: num 3
  ..$ x: num 2
```

### Doubts:

1) Why when creating the file the names both of the dataframes and of the cols of the dataframes are not included in the list?

2) quote(x) with a single dataframe works. Why not in the list?

```
> df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
> df1 <- setNames(df1, c("A", "B", quote(df1)))
> names(df1)
[1] "A"   "B"   "df1"
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 3, B = 3, C = 2)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)
names(dfList) <- c("df1", "df2") 

Map(function(df, dfn) {names(df)[3] <- dfn; df}, dfList, names(dfList))

#$df1
#  A B df1
#1 1 2   3
#
#$df2
#  A B df2
#1 3 3   2
```

You could alternatively use `setNames(df, c("A", "B", dfn))` inside the `mapply` function.

A note on OP's trial: The documentation for `quote` states:

> quote simply returns its argument.

That's why when you use `quote(x)` inside `lapply`, it simply returns the character `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for the comment on my trial.

It works perfectly on my list!

Answer (score 2):

We can `lapply()` over `names(dfList)` instead of `dfList`:

```
lapply(names(dfList), function(dfn) {
  df <- dfList[[dfn]]
  names(df)[3] <- dfn
  df
})

# [[1]]
#   A B df1
# 1 1 2   3
# 
# [[2]]
#   A B df2
# 1 3 3   2
```

There's a convenience function in `purrr` that maps over a list and its names simultaneously:

```
library(purrr)

imap(dfList, ~ {
  names(.x)[3] <- .y
  .x
})

# $df1
#   A B df1
# 1 1 2   3
# 
# $df2
#   A B df2
# 1 3 3   2
```

Or if you're after a short one-liner and don't mind hard-coding `"A"` and `"B"`:

```
imap(dfList, ~ setNames(.x, c("A", "B", .y)))
```

*(NB: Essentially those are just variations around Docendo discimus' answer).*

---

Also, not your expected output but maybe of interest for you:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(dfList, .id = "origin")

#   origin A B C
# 1    df1 1 2 3
# 2    df2 3 3 2
```

Or:

```
bind_rows(map(dfList, select, -C), .id = "C")

#     C A B
# 1 df1 1 2
# 2 df2 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the different approaches Aurèle! Never tought about lapply over the name sof the list.

Comment: Beware that the `lapply()` solution changes the names of the datasets